# How to pass html textbox value to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML textbox where user will input some string which i want to pass to a JavaScript function:

```
<input type="text" id="ad_search_query" style="width:295px">&nbsp;
<input type="button" value="<s:text name="button.search"/>" class="p-userButton"
 onClick="ADSEARCHGF.showTable('');"/>
```

Please suggest how can i do it.

Comment: Can you please post your code in details?

Comment: Use the button marked as `{}` to add 4 spaces to a line to display it as code.

Answer (score 5):

If the event is raised by the button, you will not have the text input object to pass to the function without getting it first, getting it by id is the best way.

You can use the id of the text box:

```
var searchValue = document.getElementById('ad_search_query').value;
```

in your function, or use Ahsan Rathod's method to use this code as parameter.

Comment: sorry i know this solution.. but i want to pass the value directly in function.

Comment: If the event is raised by the button, you will not have the text input object to pass to the function without getting it first, getting it by id is the best way.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
function showTable(obj){
alert(obj.value)
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="ad_search_query" style="width:295px">&nbsp; 
<input type="button" value="search" class="p-userButton" onClick="showTable(document.getElementById('ad_search_query'));"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

**JS:**

> `<script>`function showTable(val) {alert(val);} `</script>`

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="ad_search_query" style="width:295px">&nbsp; 
<input type="button" value="search" class="p-userButton" onClick="showTable(document.getElementById('ad_search_query').value);"/>
```

See this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/8ddbD/

Comment: @Tanu, which browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript function you can access textbox value like this

**var text = document.getElementsByName("textbox1").value;**

Comment: Well, it is not `getElementsByName`. Instead it should be : `var text=document.getElementById("textbox1").value;`