# how do you make a text input field open different links based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, input

I can't imagine this is very hard but i've been trying to figure out the best way to do this and  honestly im completely lost.  Now im getting frustrated so it would be great if someone who knows how to do this exactly could help me out.

I need a textbox I can embed into my html script, that will open different links depending on the users input text.

So in english here is the basics of what I need. A working script would be very much appreciated for I am stumped.

```
* stands for “any characters”


If text input contains    bbb   open link htttp://example1.com/bbb

otherwise

If text input contains   *zzz*  open link htttp://example2.com/something-predefined*zzz*

otherwise

If text input contains   *xxx* open link htttp://example3.com/something-predefined*xxx*

otherwise 

 If text input contains     *   open link htttp://example3.com/*
```

Comment: what do exactly meant by "text input"? You want a textbox or a clickable text link?

Comment: textbox. sorry for being unclear

Comment: @nvrtheless, by 'text input' cam probably means an `input` of `type="text"`. There's *no such element* as a 'textbox,' there's a `textarea`, obviously, but that's *still* not a 'textbox.'

Comment: @DavidThomas I am from ASP.Net era who thinks textbox == <input type="text" /> Sorry if I made confusion, I know the difference. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
function parmatch(input):
  if input matches /^bbb$/
    open 'http://example1.com/{input}'
    return
  if input matches /zzz/
    open 'http://example2.com/something-predefined{input}'
    return
  if input matches /xxx/
    open 'http://example3.com/something-predefined{input}'
    return
```

[MDN's article on regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: lol. thanks a lot. Ive been trying to figure it out with that page you linked me to already. still. how do I link this to a textbox?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-24874179

Comment: guess that would be explained here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107398/how-to-pass-html-textbox-value-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: im not sure why my html keeps messing this up. can u please tell me if i got this right?
 

<script>
function parmatch(input):
  if input matches /^bbb$/
    open 'http://example1.com/{input}'
    return
  if input matches /zzz/
    open 'http://example2.com/something-predefined{input}'
    return
  if input matches /xxx/
    open 'http://example3.com/something-predefined{input}'
    return
</script>

<input type="text" id="ad_search_query" style="width:295px">&nbsp; 
<input type="button" value="search" class="p-userButton" onClick="parmatch(input);"/>

Comment: What I gave is pseudocode. You need to translate it into JavaScript before it will work.

Comment: Fortunately you don't need to know Java, just JavaScript.

Comment: i really don't see how this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
    the following code only example for what you ask. here change the <a href=""> for console.

<input type="text" id="picker" />

    $('#picker').keyup(function() {
      var value = $("#picker").val();
         if(value == "1")
         {
             console.log("go to home");


         }
            else if(value == "2")
            {
                console.log("go to login");
            }
            else
                alert("plz enter valid input");
      })
```

Comment: could you please tell me what i need to do to correctly put this inside the body tags?

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete answer, I'd suggest the following:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('fire'),
    input = document.getElementById('demo'),
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    pageMap = {
        'aaa' : 'pageA',
        'bbb' : 'pageB',
        'ccc' : 'pageC'
    };

function loadPage (input, output, map) {
    var v = input.value,
        url = 'http://example.com/',
        text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    for (var i in map) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(i) && v.indexOf(i) > -1) {
            // the following shows the URL you'd end up with
            output[text] = url + map[i];
            // to *load* the URL, remove the above line,
            // and uncomment the following:
            // window.location = url + map[i];
        }
    }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    loadPage(input, output, pageMap);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PudS3/).

This answer is, however, *not* to encourage you to avoid learning JavaScript (as suggested in the comments to [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289503/82548)); please take the time to read, *at least*, the references I've supplied below.

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener).
- [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault).
- [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- [JavaScript object syntax](http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-object-syntax/).
- [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location).